# Pytest ordering from different test case files

Tags: python, pytest

Hi I use pytest and have following 2 py files in a folder.

test_abc.py as below:

```
class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setup_class(cls):
        cls.a = 10

    @classmethod
    def teardown_class(cls):
        cls.a = 20

    @pytest.mark.run(order=2)
    def test_method1(self):
       logging.warning('order2 in test_abc')
       assert (10,self.a)    # fail for demo purposes

    @pytest.mark.run(order=1)
    def test_method2(self):
        logging.warning('order1 in test_abc')
        assert 0, self.db   # fail for demo purposes
```

test_sample2.py as below,

```
class MyTest1(unittest.TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setup_class(cls):
        cls.a = 10

    @classmethod
    def teardown_class(cls):
        cls.a = 20

    @pytest.mark.run(order=2)
    def test_mtd1(self):
       logging.warning('order2 in test_samp')
       assert (10,self.a)    # fail for demo purposes

    @pytest.mark.run(order=1)
    def test_mtd2(self):
        logging.warning('order1 in test_samp')
        assert 0, self.db   # fail for demo purposes
```

Now I run using command:

```
py.test --tb=long --junit-xml=results.xml --html=results.html -vv
```

What happens here is test_method2 from both the test case files runs first (since it has been given as order1) and then test_method1 runs from both files (since it has been give as order 2)

So What I have noticed here is Ordering is overall for the test run and not for individual class/files

Is there any way to fix this issue? Right now I use ordering number for all like first file i give (1,2) then in next file i give (3,4) and it works fine.

But I don't wan't ordering in all test class only in few places I require it. Is there any hook to say pytest to see ordering only in particular file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you're using the pytest-ordering plugin -- if only particular areas in your tests require ordering, you could use relative ordering:

```
@pytest.mark.run(after='test_second')
def test_third():
    assert True

def test_second():
    assert True

@pytest.mark.run(before='test_second')
def test_first():
    assert True
```

Reference:  (http://pytest-ordering.readthedocs.org/en/develop/#relative-to-other-tests)

Comment: If all test cases are in same this is working. But if test cases are spanned across different test modules, ordering is not working. Is there any special consideration to be done ?

Comment: This is because this functionality has never been implemented in `pytest-ordering`, the linked documentation is under the header "Aspirational" - see also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62931334/pytest-ordering-relative-order-not-working). The mentioned functionality has been integrated into the fork [pytest-order](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-order/) instead (Disclaimer: I'm the author of that fork).

Comment: @SivaKumarSunku - I added a new answer to clarify this.

Answer (score 1):

I accidentally stumbled over this question, and noticed that the accepted answer will not work, so this is a correction / addendum.
The mentioned documentation for `pytest-ordering` is in a chapter titled "Aspirational", and while there has been a couple of PRs that provided that functionality, they never got merged.

As the plugin was not maintained anymore, I forked it into [pytest-order](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-order/), which is now the successor to `pytest-ordering`. It also contains the functionality for [relative markers](https://pytest-dev.github.io/pytest-order/stable/usage.html#order-relative-to-other-tests).

Using that plugin, the following will work:

```py
@pytest.mark.order(after='test_second')
def test_third():
    assert True

def test_second():
    assert True

@pytest.mark.order(before='test_second')
def test_first():
    assert True
```

Note that this is almost the same as in the accepted answer except for the marker, which in `pytest-order` is always `order`.

That may still not be the correct answer for the original question though, that asked for separate ordering in separate files. With `pytest-order`, this can be achieved by using the [--order-scope](https://pytest-dev.github.io/pytest-order/stable/configuration.html#order-scope) option. If using `--order-scope=module` in the test call, ordering is done separately in each test module. This will make the code in the question work as expected, if also replacing the markers (e.g. instead of `@pytest.mark.run(order=2)` use `@pytest.mark.order(2)`.