# pytest-ordering relative order not working?

Tags: python-3.x, pytest

I want to run some test by order, and i use pytest-ordering follow the offical article, but the order not change at all?

```py
import pytest

@pytest.mark.run(after='test_second')
def test_third():
    assert True

def test_second():
    assert True

@pytest.mark.run(before='test_second')
def test_first():
    assert True
```

It should be `test_first, test_second, test_third` order.
**But The order don't change at all ???**

```
E:\QT-learn>pytest -svv
============================================================================= test session starts =============================================================================
platform win32 -- Python 3.7.4, pytest-5.4.3, py-1.9.0, pluggy-0.13.1 -- c:\users\jekoie\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: E:\QT-learn, inifile: pytest.ini
plugins: ordering-0.6
collected 3 items                                                                                                                                                              

test_qt.py::test_third PASSED
test_qt.py::test_second PASSED
test_qt.py::test_first PASSED

============================================================================== 3 passed in 0.04s ==============================================================================

E:\QT-learn>
```

Comment: Please, explain what you are trying to do instead of just giving us code sample and output, and ask a real question.

Comment: @totok add some explain

Comment: @MrBeanBremen add this as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](https://pytest-ordering.readthedocs.io/en/develop/) of pytest-ordering has a chapter named "Aspirational" with the following note:

> This section is for functionality I’d like to implement. Documentation-driven design :)

The usage of `before` and `after` falls under this category.

You have to use the implemented functionality instead:

```py
import pytest

@pytest.mark.run(order=3)
def test_third():
    assert True

@pytest.mark.run(order=2)
def test_second():
    assert True

@pytest.mark.run(order=1)
def test_first():
    assert True
```

Note also that the method described in the documentation (using `@pytest.mark.order1` etc.) does not work with the current version - the correct version is the one in the [README](https://github.com/ftobia/pytest-ordering/blob/develop/README.md). There is a [pull request](https://github.com/ftobia/pytest-ordering/pull/56) that would fix the documentation, but the project seems to be no longer maintained.

*UPDATE:*
[pytest-order](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-order/) is a fork of `pytest-ordering` that implements this functionality (though beware the changed marker name). It is the successor of `pytest-ordering` which is no longer maintained.
*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of that fork.

Comment: I have 200 test functions, and i need some test function test relative, the `run(order=value)` is not a good solution in this case.

Comment: You could group together the related test cases (for example in a test class) and use the ordering only for these, though it may be sufficient to add the decorators only to these. Not the nicest solution, but I can't think of another.

Comment: Unfortunately, i have many test case in a same package and can't group them, i had change test case  position manually.