# Splitting up tests into separate modules

Tags: python-3.x, pytest

I have a test class with methods that each use the output of previous tests. However, one of the tests is growing way too large to keep it inside this one module (for it to remain readable), so I'd like to split it into two files:

test_mod_main.py

```py
class TestMe():
    def test_1():
        ...
    def test_2():
        ...
    def test_4():
        ...
```

mod_for_test_3.py

```py
def test_3_large():
    ...
```

And I need it to still run consecutively as if in a single test module collected from a single class, share the same data, fixtures, cmd options, everything, and run in the same order:

test_1 -> test_2 -> test_3_large -> test_4

Is it possible?

Comment: How are you executing the tests?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pytest ordering from different test case files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34524442/pytest-ordering-from-different-test-case-files)

Comment: i have one project with three modules, i can run entire project or each module separately from IDE or command line. but the third module, as described above, i need to somehow split into two files, but for them to still remain a single "virtual" module, so to speak

Comment: `class TestMe: def test_3(self): test_3_large()` and `test_3_large()` imported from another module.